# How to set environment variable for apache2 to run python cgi script

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from art import *
Art=text2art("TEST",font='block',chr_ignore=True)
print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
print('This is my test!')
print(Art)
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'art': /var/www/cgi-bin/appfolio.py
[Mon Jun 05 16:13:02.061526 2023] [cgi:error] [pid 86447] [client ::1:56248] End of script output before headers: test.py

How to set the environment path variable in apache. But when I run in pycharm its working.. requirement already satisfied